# Qual a maneira certa de declarar um array multidimensional em C#?

Tags: c#, array-multidimensional

Boa noite a todos!

Eu tentei declarar um array multidimensional em C# da seguinte maneira:

```
int[,] array1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

E a declaração funciona. Porém, também tentei fazer a declaração da seguinte maneira:

```
int[,] array1 = new int [2,3];
array1 = {{1,2,3} , {4,5,6}};
```

Declarando desse jeito, o compilador não entende a declaração do array. Fiz algo errado ou realmente não posso declarar o array multidimensional da maneira que eu fiz ? Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: C# não aceita essa sintaxe de inicialização direta em uma bidimensional. E o uso [2, 3] você está criando uma matriz com duas linhas e três colunas.

Comment: Mas eu queria mesmo criar uma matriz com duas linhas e três colunas. Então, basicamente, não posso declarar do jeito que eu tentei, é isso ?

Comment: Exato, voce nao pode. forma correta seria array1 =  new int[2, 3]{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

Comment: Certo. Vocês poderiam só colocar essa informação como uma resposta mesmo ? Acho que facilita para quem for consultar essa pergunta depois